# Работает только один VisualState

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Здравствуйте, имею вот такой простенький стиль:

```
<Style x:Key="CustomCalendarHeaderButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Style.Setters>
        <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Grid>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                    <Storyboard Storyboard.TargetName="container"
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                        <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="{DynamicResource light_background_mouseOver}"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard Storyboard.TargetName="container" 
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0.5"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Border x:Name="container" Background="Transparent">
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                              VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style.Setters>
</Style>
```

Проблема заключается в том, что программа "вылетает", когда элемент управления пытается перейти из одного `VisualState` в другой. К примеру из `Normal` в  `Disabled`. Это случается только тогда, когда для более чем одного `VisualState` определёно какое-либо действие, в случае если это сделано только для одного `VisualState`(остальные просто оставить пустыми) - всё работает отлично. Но мне же надо для каждого из них определить `Storyboard`, не зря же я их всех расписывал...

Сперва программа переходит в режим приостановки выполнения, а по завершению её выполнения, в окне вывода, я уже вижу сообщение об ошибке.

Вот скрины происходящего:

[image: Это то, что я вижу сперва, вместо "классического вылета" и сообщения об ошибке.]
[image: Изображение вывода]

Comment: Странно, у меня работает. Может, обновите Студию?

Comment: @VladD, быть может это как-то влияет, у меня этот стиль вложенный в `ControlTemplate.Resources`. Забыл уточнить, пардон.

Comment: Воспроизвелось при переходе из MouseOver к Disabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас ошибка в определении анимации. Нужно так:

```
<VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
    <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
        <Storyboard>
            <ColorAnimation
                Storyboard.TargetName="container"
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                Duration="0" To="{StaticResource light_background_mouseOver}"/>
        </Storyboard>
    </VisualState>
    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
        <Storyboard>
            <DoubleAnimation
                Storyboard.TargetName="container" 
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)"
                Duration="0" To="0.5"/>
        </Storyboard>
    </VisualState>
</VisualStateGroup>
```

---

Обратите внимание, что я не только переместил атрибуты `Storyboard.TargetXXX`, а и заменил `DynamicResource` на `StaticResource`. Динамические ресурсы (как и привязки) в анимациях не работают.

---

Разумеется, программа при неправильно определённой анимации не должна валиться с `NullReferenceException`. Это баг в WPF. [Сообщите его в Microsoft](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/61/index.html).

Comment: Вы правы, исправил и всё заработало. Более того, динамические ресурсы тоже подошли для анимации. Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: @ArthurEdgarov: Вот и отлично! Пожалуйста!

Comment: Вы знаете, в своей программе попробовал в анимациях забиндиться к файлу настроек, в котором хранятся цвета, для того, чтобы тему можно было настраивать внутри программы, и привязка заработала в анимации. Похоже так нельзя было делать раньше, но сейчас всё в порядке.
Просто решил поделиться, вдруг  Вам пригодиться :)

Comment: @ArthurEdgarov: Спасибо, не знал! А как именно вы прибиндились?

Comment: `<ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Container"
                                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                                            Duration="0"
                                                            To="{Binding Source={x:Static p:Brushes.Default}, Path=control_mouseOver_background}"/>`
Что-то наподобие такого. Где "p:Brushes.Default" - `xmlns:p="clr-namespace:WpfApp.Properties"`
Ну и цвета хранятся как `System.Windows.Media.Color`

Comment: @ArthurEdgarov: Ого, даже так работает? Спасибо!

Comment: Пожалуйста, надеюсь будет полезно Вам и другим :)